# How can I restore a deleted column in gnuCash?

Tags: gnucash

How can I restore the column, quite distressing

The **Withdrawal column is missing** in my checking account, dragging the lines between R or Deposit does not restore the Withdrawal column

gnuCash 4.6

Comment: Have you restored from a backup?  (I don't use gnucash, but that *might* work.)

Comment: I don't think the data is gone; only the GUI has been changed. This is really a question for superuser.com.

Comment: What did you do that ended up with the column disappearing?

Comment: I double-clicked the column header, poof

Comment: Resolved!   I simply closed down gnuCash and restarted and Viola the Withdrawal column reappeared.

Comment: The problem still exists: so distressing, It is related only to my assets:checking account, other accounts such as expenses:electricity have both columns

Comment: If the running balances are correct, then GNU cash *knows* about the withdrawals;  it's just not showing you...

Comment: Yup, balances are ok, it is a local configuration issue., but how can I get that Withdrawal column to display again?

Comment: Well, I upgraded to 4.6 and fussed with the deposit column header width adj and now all is well, it is nice that 4.6 has become more civilized about maintaniing its proper width.